# Are there any ways to make "snapping" feel more precise?

Tags: modeling

I'm having trouble dealing with the "snapping" element in blender. I'm used to working with Rhino where everything feels very precise and I can make sure that point intersections are right on top of each other, but Blender always feels like everything is free floating in a way that I'd like to have feel more precise like when working with rhino.

Are there any ways to make blender feel more precise?

Comment: I think the biggest misconception about blender's snapping is that you need to put the mouse cursor over the spot you want to snap to, instead of trying to line the edges/faces/verts up (Which I know is the more intuitive assumption for how it should work).